# Restore read position in dynamic content on next visit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a big chapter of a book that my user reads. Chapters can have any font-size; the window can be any size. How can I save the exact position in text (top most of currently visible window) in a database, so when user continues to read this chapter from any device, I can scroll him there?

I was trying with `window.pageYOffset`, then percentage of scroll position, but it's not accurate with dynamic window and font-size, and can only work in same environment (font-size, windows size).

My only idea now is to split the chapter into lines:

```
const lines = (chapter.match(/\r?\n/g) || '').length + 1
```

And then somehow find a line that is top most of the currently visible window, save its number, and scroll to it on load.

As an alternative, maybe something that can give me the currently top most visible html element so I can stick to it.

Any ideas?

Update: now I'm trying to get all the elements in the parent of the content `div` and iterate through them getting the element position in the viewport with `getBoundingClientRect()`. I have hopes for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you get array of paragraphs

```
let children = Array.from(contentRef.current.children)
```

Them do binary search of the closest to zero (top of the visible screen) paragraph.

```
let closestIndex = binaryClosest(
  children,
  target => 0 - target.getBoundingClientRect().y
)

localStorage.setItem('index', closestIndex)

function binaryClosest(a, compare) {
  let i = binarySearch()
  if (i === 0) return 0
  if (i === a.length) return i - 1
  let d1 = -compare(a[i]),
    d2 = compare(a[i - 1])
  return d1 < d2 ? i : i - 1

  function binarySearch() {
    let le = 0,
      ri = a.length - 1
    while (le <= ri) {
      let mid = (le + ri) >> 1,
        cmp = compare(a[mid])
      if (cmp > 0) {
        le = mid + 1
      } else if (cmp < 0) {
        ri = mid - 1
      } else {
        return mid
      }
    }
    return le
  }
}
```

Now you can save this closestIndex in database and on next load scroll to it:

```
let children = Array.from(contentRef.current.children)

window.scrollTo(0, children[localStorage.getItem('index')].offsetTop)
```